# VMWare Fusion sharing issue (mac / ubuntu)

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have an uptodate VMWare Fusion installation running Ubuntu 10.4, ever since the latest vmware fusion update I have a sharing issue between the mac and ubuntu.

Example:
I have a index.php file on my mac.
if I use ls -l this is what I see (from ubuntu)
-rw-rw-r 1 501 dialout 2075 2011-12-06 17:05 index.php

I can access the file, read it and modify it from ubuntu.

If I change this file on the mac with vi and I run ls -l again on the mac I get the following
-??????? ? ? ? ? ? index.php

and apache is unable to acces it. If I manually open and close the file on ubuntu permissions show up again as described above.

This happends with new files and modifying files, copying or moving.

Anyone has any idea what can cause it?
Thanks in foward

Comment: Probably better on superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had contact with VM Employees. It's a known bug and they are working on a fix.

The quick 'n dirty fix is to either reboot your VM, or remount the shared directory.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html. This is how I work around it for now.